# Why is Kevin in season 9 handled off screen in most episodes?

Tags: supernatural

Kevin is a recurring character in season 9. Unlike previous seasons the winchesters have a kind of "home base" in this season where they live and Kevin lives with them there and tries to translate something and otherwise does research for them sometimes.

In episodes where the plot does not need him, he is absent from the screen. But the characters talk about him, pretending he is in his room. Or they phone him, but without the otherwise usual cut to the other side showing him answering the call. It seems like the actor was not available and they try to gloss over it.

This would be a likely explanation, if the actor is famous and expensive or has some accident or other unpredicted problems. But it is unlikely that this happens several times I think. So why didn't they do one of the following:

- Just ignore it. After two or three episodes the audience will start to wonder where Kevin is. But when he appears again in an episode where he is involved in the plot the audience would say "Ah. Ok. He is still there." This "pretending he is in his room" by dialog of other characters or phone calls to him without showing him seems more to lampshade and highlight that the actor is not available than to cover it.
- It's not a daily soup. I assume it would be possible to film a few filling scenes showing him in the background or answering a generic call and cut it into the already filmed episodes when he is available again would be no problem.
- If they know he will not be available, they could even film a few such filling scenes in advance for the next episodes.

So why didn't they do one of this things and instead even lampshade the absence of the actor? Or is it a kind of Joke or reference (similiar to Howard's mother and later baby in "Big Bang Theory" that were only heard but never shown on screen)?

Not as obvious to me but still conspicuous they did similiar things with Kevin's mother and with Garth.
If I remember right they did it much better with Bobby. In most episodes where he is not involved deeply in the plot we just see him e.g. cooking in his kitchen and answering a call fom Dean or Sam. Why didn't they handle it in the other cases the same way?

Obviously this is an out of universe question.

Comment: Probably because if a character appears in a show, you need to pay them, even if it's pre-shot or archive footage. Having them be "on the phone" means that [their small fanbase won't get snippy, even if they're not really in it any more](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DemotedToExtra)